# Access methods and passing parameters to Excel .Xll add ins from C#

Tags: c#, excel-2010, xll

I need to call methods from ANALYS32.XLL Excel add-ins for analysis toolpak into mu C# application.
Please how can i call methods and pass parameters to it?
there is any way to call anova analysis in c# or not??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this will give you all the functions from the Analysis ToolPak, but it might inspire you:

The full set of financial functions from Excel have been implemented in F# - and can easily be called directly from any .NET language. You can download the latest version here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Excel-Financial-functions-6afc7d42

Answer (score 1):

```
// create new instance of Excel application
xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
// load an XLL
 xl.RegisterXLL("analys32.xll")
```

from there you should be able to access the functions in the xll via your Excel application object